# Solving equation with complex numbers: $\bar z = z^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\bar z$ be its conjugate, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Solve following equation:

$$\bar z = z^n\qquad (1).$$

My (uncomplete) solution to this:

let $z := a+bi$, where $i$ is imaginary number, and $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\bar z = a- bi$.

Using $Moivre's$ formula we get

$$z^n = r^n(\cos n\phi + i\sin n\phi),$$
where $r = |z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Now we can rewrite $(1)$:

$$a-bi = (a^2+b^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}\cdot(\cos n\phi + i\sin n\phi)$$

Is such approach useful ? I am not if I am steering into right direction, for I'm not sure how solution should look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\overline{z}=re^{-i\theta}$ so the equation is
$$re^{-i\theta}=(re^{i\theta})^n$$
$$re^{-i\theta}=r^ne^{in\theta}$$
$$r^{n-1}e^{i(n+1)\theta}=1$$
$$r=1$$
$$\theta=\frac{2\pi k}{n+1}\,\,\, k\in \{0,1,2,...,n\}$$
Edit: As stated in the comments, $z=0$ is also valid.

Comment: From what you conclude that $r=1$ and $\theta = \frac{2\pi k}{n+1}$ ?

Comment: The magnitude of the imaginary number on the LHS must be one as it is equal to one in the RHS. Then as it is in fact the $n+1$ roots of unity, the arguments are equally spaced about $2\pi$